# Mule-Hive DB connectivity returns 503 HTTP response code

Tags: hive, mule, azure-hdinsight

While trying to connect to APache hive 2.0 which is a component in HDInsight 3.6 from mule generic DB connector, I am getting the following error

> java.sql.SQLException: Cannot get connection for URL
>   jdbc:hive2://hostname:443/default;transportMode=http;httpPath=/hive2;ssl=true;trustStorePassword=******;sslTrustStore=trust.jks;user=testuser;password=******
>   : Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri:
>   jdbc:hive2://hostname:443/default;transportMode=http;httpPath=/hive2;ssl=true;trustStorePassword=******;sslTrustStore=trust.jks;user=testuser;password=******:
>   Could not create http connection to
>   jdbc:hive2://hostname:443/default;transportMode=http;httpPath=/hive2;ssl=true;trustStorePassword=******;sslTrustStore=trust.jks;user=testuser;password=******
>   . HTTP Response code: 503

The generic DB configuration looks like below :

```
<db:generic-config name="Generic_Database_Configuration" url="jdbc:hive2://hostname:443/default;transportMode=http;httpPath=/hive2;ssl=true;trustStorePassword=******;sslTrustStore=trust.jks;user=testuser;password=******" driverClassName="org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver" connectionTimeout="100000" doc:name="Generic Database Configuration"/>
```

Any help around it will be much appreciated.

Comment: Seems like a problem in Hive. Have you tried the same configuration from a different JDBC SQL client application?

Comment: @AlejandroDobniewski Yes. I am getting 503 when using other sql client as well.

Comment: You need to solve that at Hive then.